# Is there an analog of --server-dry-run option in io.fabric8.kubernetes api (Java client for kubernetes)?

Tags: java, kubernetes, java-client, kubernetes-cluster

In **command line** we can use `kubectl apply --server-dry-run -f example-pod.yml` to make a trial run of `yml` file without persisting it. 
Can we do smth similar from **Java**, using `io.fabric8.kubernetes` (Java client for kubernetes) ?

Answer (score 1):

DryRun has been implemented with version `5.2.0` according to this issue https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/2588.

It can be used like this on many resources:

```java
petClient.inNamespace(currentNamespace).withName("dry-run-delete").dryRun().delete();
```